# Why did GCP give me 6 nodes when I asked for 2?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, containers, cluster-computing, gcloud

I used these commands to create a cluster on Google Cloud Platform:

```
CLUSTER_NAME=marc-test-cluster
NODES=2
gcloud container clusters create $CLUSTER_NAME --num-nodes=$NODES --scopes storage-rw --region us-west1 --machine-type=e2-standard-2
```

But I ended up with 6 nodes:

```
kubectl get nodes
NAME                                               STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
gke-marc-test-cluster-default-pool-2d0936c5-d2j3   Ready    <none>   37m   v1.18.16-gke.302
gke-marc-test-cluster-default-pool-2d0936c5-pq11   Ready    <none>   37m   v1.18.16-gke.302
gke-marc-test-cluster-default-pool-c20c27af-p757   Ready    <none>   37m   v1.18.16-gke.302
gke-marc-test-cluster-default-pool-c20c27af-r133   Ready    <none>   37m   v1.18.16-gke.302
gke-marc-test-cluster-default-pool-f64896ca-1xk5   Ready    <none>   37m   v1.18.16-gke.302
gke-marc-test-cluster-default-pool-f64896ca-bmtw   Ready    <none>   37m   v1.18.16-gke.302
```

Why?

Answer (score 4):

Because, when used with `--region=...`, `--num-nodes` applies **per** zone in the region and there are 3 zones in `us-west1`:

```sh
REGION="us-west1"
gcloud compute zones list \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--filter="region.scope()=${REGION}" \
--format="value(name)"
us-west1-b
us-west1-c
us-west1-a
```

You can use `--zone=...` instead of `--region=...` to create only `${NODES}` nodes, or use `--region=...` and `--num-nodes=1` to create 3 nodes:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/create#--region

You can probably prove this to yourself by sorting the nodes (VMs) by zone:

```sh
gcloud compute instances list \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="value(zone.scope())" \
| sort \
| uniq --count
```

Comment: Ah!  I would not have guessed that, but it makes perfect sense!